# Installing tikz libraries

Tags: tikzlibrary

I need to install the tikz libraries such as decorations. I have a tex installation (which i suspect is an old installation) with some tikz libraries such as shapes, arrows, snakes and patterns. I am told snakes package is deprecated.

**How can I install decorations library of tikz?**

I couldn't find it in github. The repository [Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf) doesn't contain decorations library. Searching in [CTAN](https://ctan.org/) didn't help either. I am interested in decorations.pathreplacing and decorations.pathmorphing in particular.

*If the library cannot be installed, can I download the file pgflibrarytikzdecorations.code.tex and use it?*

Comment: welcome to tex.se! if you have old `latex` installation, upgrade it to recent version. with `tikz` you should have all official libraries (they are described in *tikz & pgf* manual).

Comment: As Zarko hints at, the decorations libraries are part of `pgf`/TikZ itself (which actually lives on SourceForge, not GitHub), so you should update `pgf`, or indeed the tex distribution itself. Which tex installation do you have, by the way?

Comment: Updating the tex distribution solved the problem. Sorry for the late comment.